# Nested SELECT OR INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

I am quite new with writing mysql queries and so far things have been going well although I have recently become stuck with something. What I'm trying to do is select information from another table for use in the same query. Here's what I have so far which works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM `userskinlist`
WHERE userid IN (
        SELECT userid
        FROM userlist
        WHERE authid = 'STEAM_1:0:2144092'
        )
    AND active = '1'
    AND weaponid >= '1'
    AND skinid > '0'
```

But now if the nested part does not return anything

```
(SELECT userid FROM userlist WHERE authid = 'STEAM_1:0:2144092')
```

I need to run an insert statement as follows

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO userlist (authid) VALUES ('STEAM_1:0:2144092')`
```

but I can't figure out how to add this to the same query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: why you want it on the same query? looks like you need two query, first insert and then do the select

Comment: I was under impression it would improve the efficiency if it was done in the same query? Also thanks for the edit, First time posting here :)

Comment: Dont think you get bad performance, you are doing two separated things anyway. You can wait a litle longer and see if anyone else come out with a better idea.